# How do I update the list after adding values?

Tags: flutter, dart

help me figure out how to make the list update immediately after adding values (pressing the ElevatedButton - `Navigator.of(context).pop();`).

I have this code in the main file:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'data.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: HomeScreen()));
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff313131),
        body: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: tasks.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var task = tasks[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  tasks[index].taskName,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                subtitle: Row(
                  children: [
                    task.tagOne,
                    task.tagTwo,
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: const Text('Add'),
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => AlertClass());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AlertClass extends StatefulWidget {
  const AlertClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AlertClass> createState() => _AlertClassState();
}

class _AlertClassState extends State<AlertClass> {
  late String _textValue;
  late bool _active;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _active = false;
    _textValue = 'Empty';
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: TextField(onChanged: (String value) {
        _textValue = value;
      }),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _active = !_active;
            });
          },
          child: _active ? tagOneContainer[0] : tagOneContainer[1],
        ),
           ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                    tasks.addAll({
                      TaskData(
                          taskName: _textValue,
                          tagOne:
                              _active ? tagOneContainer[0] : tagOneContainer[1],
                          tagTwo: tagTwoContainer[0]),
                    });
                });
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.add)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Essentially, when you click the ElevatedButton Alert should close and the list is updated, but it is not.
The list is only updated if you click on HotReload in Android Studio.
The tasks and other variables are taken from another file.

Comment: I think tasks list not a state variable

Comment: When you update `tasks`, you're calling `setState` on your `_AlertClassState`, but what you actually need to trigger a rebuild of is your `_HomeScreenState`.

Comment: @jamesdlin, Can you tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You can do await to your showDialog Widget. If it returns true, you can setState in your HomeScreen Class.*

**See this code:**

```
bool result = await showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => AlertClass());
     if (result== true) {
                                             
      setState(() {
        });
     }
```

Then in your ElevatedButton in AlertClass, pop with true parameter.

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                    tasks.addAll({
                      TaskData(
                          taskName: _textValue,
                          tagOne:
                              _active ? tagOneContainer[0] : tagOneContainer[1],
                          tagTwo: tagTwoContainer[0]),
                    });
                });
                Navigator.of(context).pop(true);//This will change the state 
                                                 //of your homescreen class.
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.add)),
```

Comment: Thank you!
This method should be used on all similar situations or can you tell me where I can read about other options?

Comment: Specific to this situation, we can apply this technique however state management techniques can also be used. https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options